# Get .NET Google API RefreshToken - Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, azure, oauth, google-api

I try to use this code for getting Google refresh token for the application with Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 library.
When I use it on **localhost**, **it is worked perfect**, but when I use it under an **Azure site it will be throw System.AggregateException** with Access is denied InnerException.

```
UserCredential credential =
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets()
    {
        ClientId = "<client_id>",
        ClientSecret = "<client_secret>"
    },
    new string[] { },
    Environment.UserName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    null
).Result;

string refreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
```

The inner exception is:

> InnerException Message: Access is denied   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
>      at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()

Is there any other way to get refresh token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the Azure URI as authorised in the Google console API manager?

Comment: Yes of course, I have set the http://<site>.azurewebsites.net to the Authorized JavaScript origins. I have made it for the site, and the API as well.
I use the .NET backend with System.Web.Http.ApiController because it is only data provider API backend.